# Why is a new li not added at the end?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-manipulation

I'm new to javascript and just completed a tutorial on DOM manipulation.

However, new lis are added after the fist li, not at the end (unlike the tutorial).

I would love to understand why they are added exactly there and how to add them at the end.

```js
const userList = document.querySelector(".name-list li");
const listInput = document.querySelector(".list-input");
const addListBtn = document.querySelector(".addListBtn");

addListBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    const newLi = document.createElement("li");
    const liContent = document.createTextNode(listInput.value);
    newLi.appendChild(liContent);
    userList.appendChild(newLi);
});
```

```html
<button class="addListBtn">Click me!</button>
<ul class="name-list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
<input type="text" class="list-input">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove li `const userList = document.querySelector(".name-list");`

```js
const userList = document.querySelector(".name-list");
const listInput = document.querySelector(".list-input");
const addListBtn = document.querySelector(".addListBtn");

addListBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    const newLi = document.createElement("li");
    const liContent = document.createTextNode(listInput.value);
    newLi.appendChild(liContent);
    userList.appendChild(newLi);
});
```

```html
<button class="addListBtn">Click me!</button>
<ul class="name-list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
<input type="text" class="list-input">
```

Answer (score 2):

You're appending to `userList` which is defined like:

```js
const userList = document.querySelector(".name-list li");
```

Note the `li` in the selector, so you're adding to a `li`

---

Update it to:

```
const userList = document.querySelector(".name-list");
```

So it's the list itself, not the `li` inside.

```js
const userList = document.querySelector(".name-list");
const listInput = document.querySelector(".list-input");
const addListBtn = document.querySelector(".addListBtn");

addListBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    const newLi = document.createElement("li");
    const liContent = document.createTextNode(listInput.value);
    newLi.appendChild(liContent);
    userList.appendChild(newLi);
});
```

```html
<button class="addListBtn">Click me!</button>
<ul class="name-list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
<input type="text" class="list-input">
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
function function1() {
  var ul = document. getElementById("list");
  var li = document. createElement("li");
  li. appendChild(document. createTextNode("Four"));
  ul. appendChild(li);
}
```